# Linking URLs through actions in .url format for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hyperlink, actions

I need to link some DWG files. Normally I'd do that with a simple

```
cmd /c start ""[% "Link_DWG" %]""
```

where "Link_DWG" is an attribute containing the URL of the file. My problem is that I need to link to files stored in an ECM, with its own protocol. The ECM's links work when pasted into Internet Explorer (only) or are stored in a .url file, basically like this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=protocol://yaddayadda
```

So now I need to somehow create that format from within QGIS. Is this possible?

Also this doesn't work either:

```
cmd /c start iexplore ""[% "Link_DWG" %]""
```